# How to bind event to event handler of the member field or property using XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling

Let's say I have window and I would like to handle Closed event. This is trivial:

```
Closed="Window_Closed"
```

this assumes I have Window_Closed event handler within my window. But what if I have a member (field)

```
public MySophisticatedEventHandler event_handler { private set; get; }
```

in my window, and I would like to set it like this:

```
Closed="event_handler.Window_Closed"
```

> 'event_handler.Window_Closed' is not a
>   valid event handler method name. Only
>   instance methods on the generated or
>   code-behind class are valid.

**Question** -- is there any clever way to do this using XAML? For now I set it in code, but I prefer XAML for such things.

## Edits

### 1

Just for the record. In code you simply write:

```
Closed += event_handler.Window_Closed;
```

IOW, I am looking for direct equivalent of this for XAML.

Answer (score 2):

What I typically would do is to put the sophisticated method in my ViewModel and then call it from my code behind of the view. You can use [commanding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) to bind to commands through XAML, but IMO its usually not worth the effort unless your using one of the built-in commands.

Comment: Let's say the "sophisticated" event handler lies in library (not yours). All I want to do it is bind to it -- since I can do it with one instruction in code, I was hoping I can do it with XAML too, without introducing layers of abstraction (like VM) because it is an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

you can't on WPF prior to 4.5 because event handler don't support markup extension. but with 4.5 you possibly do that check [here](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/23/wpf-4-5-part-6-markup-extensions-for-events-are-cools/) for explaination and [here](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/23/wpf-4-5s-markupextension-invoke-a-method-on-the-viewmodel-datacontext-when-an-event-is-raised/) for implementation